# Importing a sub-class in scala template -Play framework

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a package named **IndProcess** and in that package I have a class **IndicatorProcess** . In this class I have a sub-class **ExcelInd** so it looks like this **IndProcess.IndicatorProcess.ExcelInd**. I am trying to pass an **ArrayList<'ExcelInd'>** to the Scala template that I have . the code looks like this

```
@import IndProcess.IndicatorProcess.ExcelInd
@import helper._
@import java.util._
@(aaa:String,count:Int ,indList: List[IndicatorProcess.ExcelInd])
```

The error occurs as "value not found aaa" so even if I remove the aaa and just pass count still it gives me the same error.I think I am not able to import it properly. It is not able to recognize the type of List I am passing.
the calling function looks like this (currently I am just sending an empty Arraylist to display)

```
public static Result indicatorBrowse(){     
return ok(indicatorUpload.render(0,new ArrayList<ExcelInd>()));}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> The import statements should go **after** the template arguments. The 
>   template arguments must be the first line -- where it is now, it's being > parsed as a tuple with type ascriptions.

To be clear, imports were allowed to appear *before* the template's parameters shortly after this answer was written.

https://github.com/playframework/twirl/pull/12

Comment: I have tried that combination. The error I am getting is "reference to IndicatorUpload is ambiguous it it imported twice in import views.html. and import controllers.." so i changed the page name but still the error is coming..

Comment: If your page used to be called IndicatorUpload, and you have a controller with the same name, try doing a "clean" in the play console.